# Login de usuarios error al mostrar nombre de usuario loggeado

Tags: angular

Necesito poder mostrar el nombre del usuario loggeado, estoy siguiendo un tutorial y no consigo aplicar la última parte que dice lo siguiente:

> userLogged es una variable de tipo User (hace falta importar el modelo de User) que inicializo en el ngOnInit() del componente llamando al método getUserLoggedIn() del servicio de user (importado mediante inyección de dependencias).
>   https://codingpotions.com/angular-login-sesion/

Ahí les dejé también el link al tuorial, les dejo también los fragmentos de mi código tal y como está ahora, con todos los imports y todo.

**Login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from '../../services/login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private loginService: LoginService,
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

  logIn(username: string, password: string, event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Avoid default action for the submit button of the login form

    // Calls service to login user to the api rest
    this.loginService.logIn(username, password).subscribe(

      res => {
        let u: User = {username: username};        
        this.userService.setUserLoggedIn(u);

      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);

      },
      () => this.navigate()
    );

  }

  navigate() {    
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
  }
}
```

**Login.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  logIn(username:string, password:string) {
    return this.http.post('https://reqres.in/api/login', {
      email: username,
      password: password,     
    });     
  }
}
```

Y finalmente mi **user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../models/user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private isUserLoggedIn;
  public usserLogged:User;

  constructor() { 
    this.isUserLoggedIn = false;
  }

  setUserLoggedIn(user:User) {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = true;
    this.usserLogged = user;
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));

  }

  getUserLoggedIn() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
  }

}
```

A ver si alguien pudiese echarme una mano, cuando hago el login si los datos son correctos me lleva el home si los datos no son correctos no pasa por lo que yo deduzco que está funcionando correctamente todo lo anterior al tutorial.

Muchísimas gracias a todos!

**EDITO** *Añado mi home.component.ts y mi home.component.html*

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Citas } from '../../models/citas';
import { CitasService } from '../../services/citas.service'; 
import { trigger, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';
import { LoginService } from '../../services/login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  providers: [LoginService],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger(
      'enterAnimation', [
        transition(':enter', [
          style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0}),
          animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1}))
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
          style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1}),
          animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0}))
        ])
      ]
    )
  ],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    public fecha = new Date();
  public hora = this.fecha.getHours();
  public today = Date.now();
  public citas:Citas;
  constructor(
    private _citasService:CitasService,
    private _service:LoginService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCitasHome();
  }

  getCitasHome() {
    console.log('Citas cargadas correctamente');
    this._citasService.getCitasHome().subscribe(
        result => {
          if(result['code'] != 200) {
          } else {
            this.citas = result["data"];
          }
        },

        error => {
          console.log(<any>error);
        }
      );
}
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="usserLogged">
  {{userLogged.username}}
</div>
```

Comment: Puedes pintar por consola el user que llega a la función setUserLoggedIn y ver si el login te devuelve el user o solamente un Ok. Aún asi cual es tu problema?

Comment: Que no muestra nada

Comment: Nos puedes mostrar el componente Home? Pon un console antes de guardar en el localstorage para ver que esta guardando

Comment: El usserlogged lo estoy mostrando en el login.component.html para probar

Comment: Hiciste lo que te comente? Lo de mostrar por consola el user que estas almacenando en el localstorage? Primero hay que ver que estar guardando bien la información o que información te llega. Una vez realizado el login tmb puedes ir a la consola y ver que te devuelve esto localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));

Comment: Esto me devuelve: currentUser: "{\"username\":\"eve.holt@reqres.in\"}" ese es el usuario que yo puse

Comment: Pues entonces si lo esta almacenando bien, muestra tu controlador Home y el html para ver si lo estas pintando bien o no, ya que parece ir todo correcto

Comment: No lo estoy pintando en el home, estoy pintándolo en el login, ya lo he añadido al home.component.html

Comment: Comparte el codigo html de Login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si vas a mostrar en el Home en el metodo OnInit()

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 public fecha = new Date();
 public hora = this.fecha.getHours();
 public today = Date.now();
 public citas:Citas;

 usserLogged:User;

 constructor(
  private _citasService:CitasService,
  private _service:LoginService
 ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   usserLogged= this._service.getUserLoggedIn();
 }

 ...
```

y en el html

```html
<div *ngIf="usserLogged">
      {{userLogged.username}}
   </div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Puede que el fallo resida en que estas accediendo a una variable que no existe en el componente *home*, si no que existe en el servicio el cual inyectas en este componente. Prueba de la siguiente manera a ver.

```
<div *ngIf="_service.usserLogged">
   {{_service.userLogged.username}}
</div>
```

Comment: Nada, no me funciona